# Reactjs: problem converting <input type="file"> to custom button icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and trying to build an application where I want to press a custom button which will open a file dialog and upload a file on selecting it. Here is my code:

```
class ComposeButtons extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            selectedFile: null
        };
        this.myInput = React.createRef();
    }

    fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        })
    };
    triggerClick = () => {
        this.myInput.current.click()
    };

    fileUploadHandler = () => {
      /* file upload triggered */
      console.log('file upload triggered');
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div className={"composeForm-area"}>
                <div>
                    <Input
                        style={{display:'none'}}
                        type={"file"}
                        onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}
                        ref={this.myInput}
                    />
                    <Button onClick={this.triggerClick}
                            onChange={this.fileUploadHandler} 
                            style={{ backgroundColor: '#DDDCDC'}}>
                        <Icon style={{ fontSize: '20px'}} type="camera" />
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default ComposeButtons;
```

My current output:

[image]

I only get a clickable icon like above, however, upon clicking it throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.myInput.current.click is not a function
    at eval (ComposeButtons.js:88)
    at Button._this.handleClick (button.js:143)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:14
```

**What I want:**

I simply want to open a file dialog to select file when i click this camera button and after i select and press ok in file dialog, it should close and trigger `fileUploadHandler` function printing the message on the console. That's all!

**What I tried:**

Apart from code above I tried to replace code inside div in render method with this code:

```
        <div>
            <Input
                id="myInput"
                style={{display:'none'}}
                type={"file"}
                onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}
                ref={(ref) => this.myInput = ref}
            />
            <Button onClick={(e) => this.myInput.click() }
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#DDDCDC'}}>
                <Icon style={{ fontSize: '20px'}} type="camera" />
            </Button>
        </div>
```

I also followed almost all the answers on stackoverflow but nothing seems to working for me. It will be really helpful if someone can point me in right direction.

This is my first hobby project in React.

Comment: What exactly is not working? It would be helpful if you put this code on codesandbox for others to tinker with.

Comment: @MukeshSoni the problem is with the camera button which i have displayed in my question. on clicking it i get an error as shown above, instead it should open a file dialog and when i select a file in it and press `ok`, dialog should exit  triggering fileUploadHandler function which is also mentioned in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I got your question. All we can do is add a `label` tag referring to the input type `file` using the `for` attribute in the label tag. By doing this we don't need to use `ref`

For info in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Using_the_for_attribute).

Now all that needed to be done is to write appropriate css for the `label` tag

```
<div>
  <label htmlFor="myInput"><Icon style={{ fontSize: '20px'}} type="camera" /></label>
  <input
    id="myInput"
    style={{display:'none'}}
    type={"file"}
    onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}
  />
</div>
```

After that, to trigger file upload. we can call `fileUploadHandler` after `fileSelectedHandler` is called.

```
fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
  }, () => this.fileUploadHandler());
};
```

Comment: hi raman, thank you. your code works perfectly fine. It opens a file dialog where i can choose a file, however could you explain after selecting a file from file dialog where exactly can i invoke `fileUploadHandler` function as shown in my question? in your answer you only trigger `fileSelectedHandler` function on change

Comment: you can call `fileUploadHandler` after the file change is triggered. I have edited the answer.

Comment: thanks for this solution, I wasted many hours in search of this. Now it fully works

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library instead of building this yourself. Handle files can be tricky as soon as you want to do just a little more. Try out https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone. It works great and is simple to use.

Comment: @Dhruvify Did you try it out or did you go with your own approach?

Comment: I went with the approach mentioned here in the accepted answer above. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using hooks there is a package that solves your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-file-picker

```
import { useFilePicker } from 'use-file-picker';

function App() {
  const [filesContent, errors, openFileSelector] = useFilePicker({
    multiple: true,
    accept: '.ics,.pdf',
  });

  if (errors.length > 0) return <p>Error!</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => openFileSelector()}>Reopen file selector</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(filesContent)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created this hook for the same reason as you have.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Links are great, but showing how whey solve the question is much better.